# Lenovo 300e 2nd Gen MTK

Tags: chromebook

My school let me keep one of the managed Chromebooks after I transferred to another school. That Chromebook was a Lenovo 300e 2nd Gen Mtk.

I'd like to know if there was a way for me to remove Enterprise Enrollment from my managed Chromebook? I tried the  Escape key, refresh, and power trick and it doesn't work. Also, the powerwash doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Almost same problem here.
I have an LG 22CV241.  It was managed by a company too. I managed to recover it but now no matter which Wi-Fi network it is connected, even by Ethernet cable, it give the same error.

[image: screenshot]

Regarding to your question you can try to create an USB recovery: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-chromebooks-series/300e-chromebook-2nd-gen-mtk/solutions/ht117511-how-to-create-a-usb-recovery-drive-and-use-drive-to-recover-windows-10

It took a while, but I figured it out. The problem was the recovery image *"chromeos_13099.110.2"*. I think this is the latest version that Google offers for recovery. I found an older one on this website: [googleapps.chatham-nj.org/CrOS/](https://googleapps.chatham-nj.org/CrOS/) and problem disappeared.